# Which member of the Hemiptera family could this bug belong to?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Today I found this little bugger on the outside stucco near Vienna (AUT). Though I'm a big fan of bugs in general, certain members of the Pentatomidae, or their super-family the Pentatomoidea, especially the Palomena prasina (European shield bug) is not one of my favourites since their stink glands on the abdomen can secrete a foul-smelling and long-lasting secretion.

To my surprise, this quite beautifully ornamented bug with a length of about 7-8 mm didn't seem to tend to secretion even when stressing him a bit with a cotton swab (Disclaimer: no bugs were harmed during this test).

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me identify this bug which seems to belong to the Hemiptera family (just my assumption, please correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Nezara viridula*, Green Vegetable Bug (and other names).

Probably fifth instar, as the body is mostly green.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nezara_viridula

Found by searching images using the terms:

green stink bug with four rows of yellow dots

[image]
Photo by Charles Schurch Lewallen, under Creative Commons license. Found at https://bugguide.net/node/view/8819

Comment: Thx for your id and the link, looks like the one I photographed is the [Fifth instar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nezara_viridula#/media/File:Pentatomidae_-_Nezara_viridula-005.JPG). I didn't know they moult five times before reaching maturity and have different color morphs - quite impressive!

Comment: You are right, I change my answer.